# Changing the values of variables throughout a notebook

Tags: notebooks, variable-definitions

I have a model with many parameters, and I'd like to see how the model changes when some of those parameters change.

Right now many of those parameters are set to prescribed values, i.e., `Tin = 300`. I want to do something like this:

```
Table[Qout, {Tin, 100, 1000}]
```

However, I didn't specify `Qout` as a function of `Tin` from the beginning. Going back and correcting this would be very tedious (would have to change many downstream functions and their references). In addition, I may want to vary other parameters I haven't thought of yet at some later point.

Is there a way to get around re-defining all the functions and the function references here?

Comment: That really depends on how you defined your functions. For example compare these: `param = 1;
f[x_] = param x^2;
g[x_] := param x^2;
Table[f[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {param, 0, 1, 0.1}]
Table[g[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {param, 0, 1, 0.1}]`. It might help to delete the parameter assignments right in the beginning, but it is not guaranteed to work (e.g., it will break when some intermediate results need numerical arguments). You might be better off in the long rung by adopting a programming style that defines everything depending on parameters as functions.

Comment: Yah the problem is that I have some intermediate results that need numerical arguments (i.e FindRoot, NSolve). My parameter set is huge (~20), and it is not obvious from the beginning which parameters were important. I now recognize 5 or 6 that could be important, and I want to vary those.

Comment: What you can try to do is to use the whole notebook as a function. Erase the parameter definitions at the beginning and save it in a new file. Then create a new notebook for the parameter tests, and write something like `With[{param1 = 1,...}, <<execution code here>>]` where `<<execution code here>>` loads the other file and executes it. `NotebookGet` and `NotebookEvaluate` may be relevant. Of course, this can also be done in loops for testing ranges of parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has already been said in a comment, a lot depends on how you defined quantities intermediate between strictly numerical parameters such as `Tin` and final output represented by `Qout`. A typical beginner situation often looks like this:

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 3;

a = x + y;
b = y z;
q = a/b
```

which gives q a value of 1/2 and destroys the symbolic definitions of `a, b, q`.

However, if you are willing to rewrite the above definitions slightly, you can preserve the symbolic definitions. In this example, the second block of code is rewritten as:

```
Clear[a, b, q]
a := x + y
b := y z
q := a/b
```

Now `Block` can be used to make a table in which a parameter varies over a range of values.

```
Block[{y}, Table[q, {y, 3}]]
```

> {2/3, 1/2, 4/9}

Note that the other free variables, `x` and `z`, still have their top-level values because the weren't blocked by `Block`.

If this approach won't work in your situation, I think you need give us more details about that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to make your whole notebook into a function, with arguments that are all the values that you want to have be flexible. So if your notebook contains:

```
a = 5; b = 10;
ns = NSolve[a x + b == 0, x];
x /. ns
```

You can change this into a function by:

```
f[a_, b_] := Module[{x}, 
                ns = NSolve[a x + b == 0, x]; 
                x /. ns
             ]
```

To evaluate, call the function with the desired values like f[5,10] or call the function many times using Table or Map or Do. For example:

```
Table[f[a, b], {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 3}]
```